# Need a help 'import random' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, fractals

this is a translator), I need to make sure that 2 fractals (drawn with turtle) are drawn randomly when the project is opened (either the first fractal or the second), could you tell me which commands should be added to the beginning of the code so that random selection of a fractal, thanks.

```
  import turtle as tu, random

def Koch(length):

if length <= 2 :
tu.fd(length)
return
Koch(length/3)
tu.lt(60)
Koch(length/3)
tu.rt(120)
Koch(length/3)
tu.lt(60)
Koch(length/3)


tu.speed(166)
length = 300.0
tu.penup()
tu.backward(length/2.0)
tu.pendown()
Koch(length)
tu.done()

triangle = turtle.Turtle()
triangle.ht()
triangle.speed(10)
triangle.pencolor('blue')

triangle.speed(0)
points = [[-175,-125],[0,175],[175,-125]] 

 def getMid(p1,p2):
  return ( (p1[0]+p2[0]) / 2, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 2) 

def triangle(points,depth):

triangle.up()
triangle.goto(points[0][0],points[0][1])
triangle.down()
triangle.goto(points[1][0],points[1][1])
triangle.goto(points[2][0],points[2][1])
triangle.goto(points[0][0],points[0][1])

 if depth>0:
    triangle([points[0],
                    getMid(points[0], points[1]),
                    getMid(points[0], points[2])],
               depth-1)
    triangle([points[1],
                    getMid(points[0], points[1]),
                    getMid(points[1], points[2])],
               depth-1)
    triangle([points[2],
                     getMid(points[2], points[1]),
                     getMid(points[0], points[2])],
               depth-1)
```

triangle(points,6)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please ask specific questions and do not ask users to "finish your code" for you. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me what to do in order to select a fractal for drawing at random at the opening of the project

Comment: @Jisurane Yeah, you use the random module for that.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing we need to do is reorganize your code from a random soup of functions, data and test calls to a library of functions from which we can select one.  And share a common turtle.

As far as selecting a random fractal to draw, the **random** library has a number of functions we can use to choose between two options.  In this example I'm going to use the `choice()` function to do so:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def koch(length):
    if length <= 2:
        turtle.forward(length)
        return

    koch(length/3)
    turtle.left(60)
    koch(length/3)
    turtle.right(120)
    koch(length/3)
    turtle.left(60)
    koch(length/3)

def getMid(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] + p2[0])/2, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 2)

def triangle(points, depth):

    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(points[0][0], points[0][1])
    turtle.down()
    turtle.goto(points[1][0], points[1][1])
    turtle.goto(points[2][0], points[2][1])
    turtle.goto(points[0][0], points[0][1])

    if depth > 0:
        triangle([points[0],
            getMid(points[0], points[1]),
            getMid(points[0], points[2])],
            depth - 1)
        triangle([points[1],
            getMid(points[0], points[1]),
            getMid(points[1], points[2])],
            depth - 1)
        triangle([points[2],
            getMid(points[2], points[1]),
            getMid(points[0], points[2])],
            depth - 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from random import choice

    LENGTH = 300

    POINTS = [[-175, -125], [0, 175], [175, -125]]

    screen = Screen()

    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.pencolor('blue')

    if choice(['koch', 'triangle']) == 'koch':
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.backward(LENGTH / 2)
        turtle.pendown()

        koch(LENGTH)
    else:
        triangle(POINTS, 6)

    screen.exitonclick()
```